# How to copy files nested in directories that match a pattern?

Tags: filesystems, directory, files, rsync, file-copy

I'm looking to copy files from subdirectories that match this pattern

```
vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake
```

into a folder

```
lib/tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds pretty easy:

```
cp vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake lib/tasks
```

Or if the first `*` should match a whole subtree, use something like:

```
find vendor/plugin -path "*/tasks/*.rake" -exec cp "{}" lib/tasks +
```

Comment: You can't use `-exec cp {} arg +` that way. With `+`, `{}` has to be the last argument. So `-exec sh -c 'exec cp "$@" lib/tasks' sh {} +`

Comment: Note that with `find`, both `*` will match any number of subdirectories, so it would match on `vendor/plugin/a/b/c/tasks/e/f/g/h.rake` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to handle name collisions (for example, the collision that would occur between `vendor/plugin/a/tasks/1.rake` and  `vendor/plugin/b/tasks/1.rake`) by being notified about them instead of overwriting files, then use a  shell loop:

```bsh
destdir=lib/tasks

for pathname in vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake
do
    destpath=$destdir/${pathname##*/}

    if [ -e "$destpath" ]; then
        printf 'Can not move "%s", "%s" is in the way' \
            "$pathname" "$destpath" >&2
        continue
    fi

    cp "$pathname" "$destpath"
done
```

The line

```bsh
destpath=$destdir/${pathname##*/}
```

could also be written as

```bsh
destpath=$destdir/$(basename "$pathname")
```

and simply constructs the pathname for the destination for the sake of checking whether it's already taken.

You could also just do

```bsh
cp -i vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake lib/tasks
```

to get an interactive prompt for each name collision from the `cp` utility  itself.  The command relies on expanding the `vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake` pattern on the command line, and depending on how many pathnames that expands to, it may potentially trigger a "argument list too long" error, in which case a loop may be used instead:

```bsh
for pathname in vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake
do
    cp -i "$pathname" lib/tasks
done
```

This loop is pretty much identical to the initial loop in this answer.  The only difference is that we let the `cp` utility prompt the user whenever there is a name collision.

All variations above assume that the pattern `vendor/plugin/*/tasks/*.rake` actually matches something and that the destination directory `lib/tasks` already exists.  I also assume that you are not interested in subdirectories or files with hidden names.